# Display all employees where employees hired before 21-NOV-1989 (1989-11-21) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, date, mysql-workbench, rdbms

My Database has a table named "employee" and "hire_date" column in it. I tried to fire following Query, but got empty set:

```
mysql> SELECT * from employees
    -> WHERE hire_date < 1989-11-21;

       Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Though I have records with hire_date before 21 NOV 1989. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to wrap `1989-11-21` in single quotes. So it will be `'1989-11-21'`

Comment: Yes: 1989 minus 11 minus 21 is 1957

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date literals in MySQL typically require single quotes, so use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE hire_date < '1989-11-21';
```

Note that this assumes that your `hire_date` column be actually date or datetime, or, if text, that you are storing your text dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! hire_date has 'date' data type. Will your suggestion work on it too?

Comment: It will work with either date or datetime.  But keep in mind that if `hire_date` were datetime, the above query  would exclude the entire date `21-NOV`.

Comment: Okay for sure!!